# Find $\lim\limits_{|X| \rightarrow \infty} f(X)$, if it exists$f(X) = \frac {\log(x^2+2y^2+4z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $

Tags: real-analysis

> find $\lim\limits_{|X| \rightarrow \infty} f(X)$, if it exists
>
> $$f(X) = \frac {\log(x^2+2y^2+4z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$

Given the following definition:

> > If $D_f$ is unbounded, we say that $\lim\limits_{|X| \rightarrow \infty } f(X) = L$,
> >
> > If for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a number $R$ s.t. $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$ whenever $|X| \geq R$ and $X \in D_f$

.

I note that
$$f(X) = \frac {\log(x^2+2y^2+4z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} < \frac{1}{|X|^2}$$
So if 
$$|X|>1/{\sqrt{\delta}}$$ 
we have
$$f(X) = \frac {\log(x^2+2y^2+4z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} < \frac{1}{|X|^2}< \delta$$

Trying to understand the definition written at the top. How would you apply the definition with $R$?

Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry but $$f(X)  < \frac{1}{|X|^2}$$
 is wrong in general. But your idea is good, only it must be refined.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(X)|\leq $ $\left|\frac {\log (4x^2+4y^2+4z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|=$ $\left|\frac {\log (|X|^2) +\log 4}{|X|^2}\right|$ which goes to $0$ as $|X|\to \infty.$